# Will Google Analytics 'linker' work between a site using analytics.js and a site using gtag.js?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Suppose a *source* website is using *analytics.js* and wants to track cross-domain activity via the "linker" plugin/parameter to a *destination* website that is using *gtag.js*.

Based on [these **analytics.js** docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker) and [these **gtag.js** docs,](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cross-domain) I expect it to work fine.

### Source Site (analytics.js)

**[Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker) Excerpt**

> Once run, analytics.js will listen for clicks on links that point to the destination domain (or domains) and add the linker parameter to those links immediately prior to navigation starting.

**Code**

```
ga('create','UA-XXXXXXXXX-1','auto');
ga('send','pageview');
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['mydestinationsite.com'], false, true);
```

### Destination Site (gtag.js)

**[Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cross-domain) Excerpt**

> On the destination domain, when a value is configured for the domains property of the linker parameter, gtag.js will check for linker parameters in the URL. If the linker parameter is found and is valid, gtag.js extracts the client ID from the parameter and stores it.

**Code**

```
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-2', {
  'linker': {
    'domains': ['mysourcesite.com']
  }
});
```

**Will the destination site using gtag.js check for a parameter in the URL and operate properly?**